# Ruby 2.2.1 in Vagrant VM using Chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, bundler

I want to setup my new **development environment for a rails app** using [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [chef](https://www.chef.io/).

**Goal**

Clone repository (see below). Then run:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Finally running `bundle install` in app folder should work using installed ruby 2.1.2.

I already **have gone through several tutorials** that describe how to to this using various cookbooks and different strategies (rbenv, rvm, ruby-install, ruby-build). But although sometimes the machine could be provisioned correctly, I was never able to ssh into the machine and run `bundle install` without the following error message:

```
The program 'bundle' is currently not installed. To run 'bundle' please ask your
administrator to install the package 'bundler'
```

I will now present **my most recent attempt** based on this tutorial:
http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/chef-basics-for-rails-developers/

I have uploaded it to github here:
https://github.com/denniske/vagrant-chef-ruby

After creating vagrant machine and provisioning and ssh into machine, I get the following:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ bundle
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cd /usr/local/ruby/2.1.2/bin

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/usr/local/ruby/2.1.2/bin$ ls
erb  gem  irb  rake  rdoc  ri  ruby  testrb
```

**Problem 1: It seems the default ruby is the ruby used by chef for provisioning (1.9.3) which I do not want to use for my rails application.**

`bundler` is successfully installed, but connected to default (wrong) ruby version.

Ruby 2.2.1 was installed into `/usr/local/ruby/2.1.2`.

Problem 2: By using some code like this in default.rb I seem to be able to **make my ruby version the default, but then bundler does not work**.

```
link "/usr/bin/ruby" do
  to "/usr/local/ruby/2.1.2/bin/ruby"
end

link "/usr/bin/gem" do
  to "/usr/local/ruby/2.1.2/bin/gem"
end
```

Does anybody has an idea how to fix this / can create a pull request to get this working?

Comment: Inspect your path, I'm pretty sure /usr/local/ruby/2.1.2/bin is not in your path as you didn't ask rvm or rbenv to set it as default system wide. Moreover vagrant do a `sudo chef-client` so inspecting vagrant user environment gives you a different view than the root environment.

Comment: @Tensibai So I would need to add `/usr/local/ruby/2.1.2/bin` to the path of user `vagrant` instead of creating the symlinks?

Comment: If you're using rvm, there's a `rvm default 'version'` command somewhere, I'm pretty sure the cookbook allow to manage it but you'll probably have to work with a two pass chef run so the environment is updated

Comment: To complement previous comment we're on a whole different subject (managing a two pass run) and I didn't had to really work on this subject, I'm giving clues, if it's the way we probably have to move to chat to figure this out properly (unless someone with a good background do a nice answer)

Comment: @Tensibai You are probably right. As I have a working solution now using another cookbook with rbenv, I cannot invest more time into this stuff. I will just accept my answer where I described how I did it in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry this is not really a direct answer to my original question, but I solved the problem another way and wanted to share it with you.

I found the website rove.io and chose Languages > Ruby > rbenv > 2.1.2, downloaded the package. Then I added the bundler gem to the chef.json config in the downloaded Vagrantfile:

```
chef.json = {
      :rbenv => {
        :user_installs => [
          {
            :user   => "vagrant",
            :rubies => [
              "2.0.0-p647"
            ],
            :global => "2.0.0-p647",
            'gems'    => {
              '2.0.0-p647'    => [
                {
                  'name'    => 'bundler',
                  'version' => '1.10'
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Then I created the vagrant machine and **everything just worked as it should**.

Note: I already tried using rvm and chef before with ubuntu 14. That did not work (due to some strange errors). But the ubuntu version used by the rove.io Vagrantfile works.

Comment: In my experience, rbenv has worked out better, esp. on server-side. I'm glad everything's worked out. Unless you're using OS-native ruby, version managers are recommended since native-OS ruby isn't always what you need (and upgrades aren't always possible nor available).

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is an issue with the `gem_package` command.

I was able to make it work by replacing with an `execute` resource as

```
execute "install gem" do
  command "gem install bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri"
end
```

and remove

```
gem_package 'bundler' do
  options '--no-ri --no-rdoc'
#  gem_binary "/usr/local/ruby/2.1.2/bin/gem"
end
```

Comment: Like `gem_package` this will install bundler for the chef ruby version (1.9.3) not for my newly installed ruby (2.1.2). So when running bundle install in my project folder, I will get `Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2`

Comment: @Dennis Indeed, per the [documentation](http://docs.chef.io/client/resource_gem_package.html) if your ruby is not native (rvm or rbenv) it will use chef's ruby which is in path and you have to specify the `gem_binary`attribute to load in the correct environment. Calling an execute resource does nothing different.

Answer (score 0):

i will not specify the cookbook implementation itself, though what you will need to achieve is the following:

1. install your favorite `ruby` version (including `gem`).
2. update default `ruby` and `gem` symlinks, see: `/usr/bin/ruby` and `/usr/bin/gem`.
3. install your favorite `bundler` version.

you can achieve what you want by implementing `minitests` (see [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest), and [chef-minitest-handler](https://github.com/chef/minitest-chef-handler))